# Looping an array to list items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In my frontend Reactjs app, I upload multiple images at the same time and save the urls in an array. When trying to loop an array which contains url to display on website, it shows each image in a separate box (which is good). However, when I click on a single image, it renders all the image urls in the array as per console log.

When I click a single image this shows up in console log:

> http://192.168.22.124:3000/source/5102018114022AM-pexels-photo.jpg
>   http://192.168.22.124:3000/source/5102018114022AM-redhat.jpg

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({ isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn})
}

render() {
const { name, fileExt, pic } = this.state;
var img = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
  console.log(pic[i]);
    img.push(<a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} key={i} className={'tc ' + change + ' dib br3 ma2 pa2 grow bw2 shadow-5'} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <div key={i}>
      <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc br3' alt='robots' key={i} src={`${pic[i]}`}/>
      </div>
      </a>)
};

  return (
    isToggleOn && fileExt !== 'mp4' ?
    <div>
    { img }
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show the handleClick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are `console.log`ing inside the loop in your render function. So whenever the content is rerendered, it will loop through and console.log multiple times. Because your `handleClick` method is calling `setState`, the component will be rerendered, which calls the `render()` function again and then `console.log` in the loop.

It sounds like what you want is it to only console.log the item you click on. If that's the case, then you would put your `console.log` inside the `handleClick` method which you would pass the parameter to:

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(p)}
```

Also a much better way to do this is to use `.map` like below:

```
handleClick(url) {
  console.log(url);
  this.setState({ isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn});
}

render() {
  const { name, pic } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {pic.map((p, i) => (
        <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} key={p} className={'tc ' + change + ' dib br3 ma2 pa2 grow bw2 shadow-5'} onClick={() => this.handleClick(p)}>
          <div>
            <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc br3' alt='robots' src={p}/>
            <h2 style={{position: "absolute", top: 185, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0}} className='f6 measure-narrow lh-copy'>{name[i]}</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also note: you only need `key=` on the outer element inside a loop.

Comment: Now console log is also showing this: Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}

Comment: @TedKhi Check to make sure the `onClick` passes the parameter using an arrow function: `onClick={() => this.handleClick(p)}`

Comment: I am using arrow function and was still getting that Proxy message.
 I have updated my question. this.handleClick() is already doing something. So I have to call a separate function for logging the url and it works..
 onClick={() => { this.handleClick(); this.urlLog(p);}}

Comment: I have one more question. if I have another array called 'name' which contains names for each files. How can I loop for it inside pic map loop so each file has its name displayed. 
....
<h2 style={{position: "absolute", top: 185, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0}} className='f6 measure-narrow lh-copy'>{name}</h2>
...........

Comment: @TedKhi I updated my answer. I see what you're saying with the two arrays. It would be better if they could be combined into an array of objects, but the `.map` can have a second parameter `i` for the index. Then you can do `name[i]`, also updated the `handleClick` method to add the `setState` so you don't have to do it inline.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly. But I want to understand that why we only mentioned pic.map with a second parameter of 'i'  for name array and only used name[i]? How does it work? why not name.map?

Comment: `.map` just loops through each item. Since the two arrays have the same number of elements, you can just use the second parameter for the index. Usually you won't use this for `.map` and the best way would be to combine the two arrays into a single array of objects. Then you would do something like `combined.map((item) => console.log(item.name, item.pic));

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, is this how we create an array of object... var list = [ { url: ['www.1.com', 'www.2.com'] }, { name: ['alex', 'tim'] } ]  and then map it?

Comment: `list = [ { url: 'www.1.com', name: 'alex' }, { url: 'www.2.com', name: 'tim' } ];` then you would do something like `list.map((item) => console.log(item.url, item.name));`